# What GPU to run llama-2 13B locally?

Tags: llama-2, gpu

I've installed llama-2 13B on my machine. While it performs ok with simple questions, like 'tell me a joke', when I tried to give it a real task with some knowledge base, it takes about 10-15 minutes to process each request. I'm wondering what acceleration I could expect from a GPU and what GPU I would need to procure.

Comment: What kind of knowledge base? How do you access it?

Comment: A few sample rows from DB and somewhat lengthy instructions. Totals up to a few KB. All packed into the prompt.

Comment: Thanks, so you want the LLM to tell you something about the sample rows, right?

Comment: I'm essentially trying to get it to generate SQL queries for data analytics. For this I'm rying to feed it some information abotu the data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing A10G works for llama2 13b (I have tried it on [Lightinig AI](https://lightning.ai/))
it has 24Gb

i think same goes to 3090 and 4090

Comment: Anything more affordable? A10G runs at $2800.

Comment: RTX 3090 maybe more affordable 

this is maybe a useful discussion for you : [link](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama/issues/79#issuecomment-1454687232)

Answer (score 0):

3080/3090 going with chill. I have 1660 TI and i runned llama-2 7B locally without any problem. So 13B should be good on 3080/3090.